# How to access variable from multiple button handlers

Tags: c#

In my app, the user can browse and select a text file. I'm saving the path like this:

```
private void nacitanie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "Otvoriť Textový súbor.";
        dialog.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = dialog.FileName;
        }
    }
```

Then I need to work with that path in other buttons. How can I return the path of the text file from the button handler method?

Answer (score 1):

You should create `path` outside `nacitanie_Click`:

```
class SomeClass
{
private string path;
.....
private void nacitanie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "Otvoriť Textový súbor.";
        dialog.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = dialog.FileName;
        }
    }
....
}
```

and the use it in another methods/handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable outside of the button handler method:

```
private string path = string.Empty;

private void nacitanie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Title = "Otvoriť Textový súbor.";
        dialog.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = dialog.FileName;
        }
    }
```

That way, you'll be able to access the variable from other button handlers.